# Force stop a NSOperation or GCD?

Tags: ios, nsoperation

In my app I am running a server in the background. I am using a `NSOperation` to do so. (I used GCD before but I need to be able to stop it, so I switched to `NSOperation`, but I still cannot figure out how.)

So essentially, my `NSOperation` subclass looks like this:

```
- (void)main {
    server_main(var1, var2);
}
```

Since this is a server, the `server_main` function basically does not return. I also have no control to the implementation of that function.

Occasionally, the user changes the settings of the server. When this occurs, I would like to stop and then restart the server. If I understand correctly, I need to do something like `if (self.isCancelled)` in the `NSOperation` subclass, but since it will be stuck in the `server_main` function, I doubt it will actually work.

So how can I stop the server?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it properly see [Responding to Cancellation Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW24) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide,* which says:

> Although the `NSOperation` class provides a way for clients to cancel an operation, recognizing the cancellation event is voluntary by necessity. If an operation were terminated outright, there might not be a way to reclaim resources that had been allocated. As a result, operation objects are expected to check for cancellation events and to exit gracefully when they occur in the middle of the operation.
>
> To support cancellation in an operation object, all you have to do is call the object’s `isCancelled` method periodically from your custom code and return immediately if it ever returns `YES`.

This is a long winded way of saying that I really think you need to be able to change `server_main` so that it either:

- Check `isCancelled` periodically, or
- Have it provide a callback/progress delegate method block so you can do that yourself as well as some additional function/method you can call to cancel `server_main`, letting it to the critical clean-up process.

If you just start killing processes (if you even can), you will undoubtedly leak resources or leave that `server_main` in an inconsistent state.

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but it's the way canceling of operations work. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I figured.... I'm aware of this but the problem is I cannot modify `server_main` for some reason. Otherwise I will totally do that.

Comment: @iBlue - Sorry about that. It's a drag, but that `server_main` effectively needs to offer one of those two techniques to be cancelable. (Sigh.) Is `server_main` something you can replace with something that does permit cancelation? (e.g. some frameworks can be added as a library or can have their source compiled as part of the project; if you had source you could edit that) Or are you stuck with it as it is?

Comment: Yes sadly I'm stuck with it as it is... >< Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
- (void)setSuspended:(BOOL)suspend
```

method on NSOperationQueue? And before adding a new operation, check if the queue is suspended with isSuspended?

**Edit :** Here parameter **suspend**
If YES, the queue stops scheduling queued operations for execution. If NO, the queue begins scheduling operations again.
Discussion
This method suspends or resumes the execution of operations. Suspending a queue prevents that queue from starting additional operations. In other words, operations that are in the queue (or added to the queue later) and are not yet executing are prevented from starting until the queue is resumed. Suspending a queue does not stop operations that are already running.

Operations are removed from the queue only when they finish executing. However, in order to finish executing, an operation must first be started. Because a suspended queue does not start any new operations, it does not remove any operations (including cancelled operations) that are currently queued and not executing.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So when I suspend a queue, it stops the operation contained no matter what? But is the operation merely suspended, not stopped? I need to stop it and start a new copy... Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's from Apple's documentation. And as I said, it does not force stop the running operation so it does not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
@interface Canceller
{
    BOOL _shouldCancel;
}
- (void)setShouldCancel:(BOOL)shouldCancel;
- (BOOL)shouldCancel;
@end

@implementation Canceller
- (void)setShouldCancel:(BOOL)shouldCancel {
    _shouldCancel = shouldCancel;
}
- (BOOL)shouldCancel {
    return _shouldCancel;
}
@end

static void test(int a){
    static Canceller * canceller = nil;

    if(q){
        [canceller setShouldCancel:YES];
        [canceller release];
        dispatch_suspend(q);
        dispatch_release(q);
        q=nil;
    }
    canceller = [[Canceller alloc] init];
    q=dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);
    dispatch_async(q,^ {
        while(![canceller shouldCancel]){NSLog(@"query %d",a);sleep(2);}
    });

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. But unless you understand what's going on with the code (which I believe is from another SO post), I don't think it works for my case. If you think otherwise, any elaboration is appreciated.

Comment: Do u adding NSOperation in a operation queue or not? If you are adding in a operationqueue, then you can call a method [queue cancelalloperations];

Comment: that does not help either apparently, since they are the same thing